# connecting header.php up a file level

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to connect my PHP header from a file that is in a folder.

I'm attempting to do this by using:

```
<?php include("../header.php"); ?>
```

It works to bring the content in that file on the page, but its not applying the style.css file to the doc. Why?

Here is the contents of header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>%TITLE%</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <h2 id="logo">Some Company</h2>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
            <a href="rentals.php">Rentals</a>
            <a href="forsale.php">For Sale</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="mainContent">
```

Comment: open ur pges with firebug and see which CSS is not loading, and u will probably see why too

Comment: You should note that the `<link>` tag `href` property is relative to the file that is calling the `include()` and **not** relative to the `header.php` file. So, if you are loading `somefolder/pages/page.php` and you're including `somefolder/header.php`, you are fetching `somefolder/pages/style.css` and not `somefolder/style.css`. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because its trying to reference the css at 'style.css' but try putting '../style.css'.  It should allow the styles but it won't fix all your pages. In that case its better to use something like this:

```
<?php
    // Set a constant with your url
    define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:64411/TestingPHPStuff/');

    echo 'Now use it in your html like this:';
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=BASE_URL;?>style.css"/>
```

That way file location does not matter.

Basically though, you are trying to use a stylesheet that doesn't exist at that current level.  Probably.

**Edited**
I changed it.  If you include the 'http://' and the port ':64411' (for example you would use your port) then it should work.  I just tested it and it only worked for me with both 'http://' and ':64411'.

Comment: I'm currently developing the site locally. When I define the BASE_URL as "localhost/someCompany/" it returns "localhost/someCompany/localhost/someCompany/index.php" When developing locally, do I simply define BASE_URL as "/"?